# typescript type return from String.concat

Tags: arrays, string, typescript, types, type-conversion

I have a function that converts an integer to English words. I chain the array operations to convert the number in one go. The problem I have is in reduce() I have an array concat() which should always return string[] type, however typescript compiler complains that the type returned from reduce() is string[] | string. Therefore the map() after reduce() can't be called and tsc complains 'map does not exist on type string'.

```
inEnglish(n: number): string {
    return n === 0? 'zero': n.toLocaleString().split(',')
            .reverse()
            .map((g, i) => Number(g)? [g, scales[i]]: g)
            .reverse()
            .reduce((g: string[], a) => g.concat(a), [])
            .map(g => Number(g)? this.under1000(Number(g)): g)
            .join('')
}
```

Since I know that concat() will always return type string[], how can I tell tsc that it will always be type string[] and not type string?

Comment: `scales: string[]` ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes, scales is of type string[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be to specify the result of `reduce` explicitly:

```
var scales :string[] =[]
function inEnglish(n: number): string {
    return n === 0? 'zero': n.toLocaleString().split(',')
            .reverse()
            .map((g, i) => Number(g)? [g, scales[i]]: g)
            .reverse()
            .reduce<string[]>((g, a) => g.concat(a), [''])
            .map(g => Number(g)? this.under1000(Number(g)): g)
            .join('')
}
```

Comment: Tried that. Works nicely. Thank you for your help.